# How can I connect SQL Server to MongoDB for Real time data replication?

Tags: data-synchronization

You will find three tables. Restore those in MSSQL with a db name "source_db". Create a database in Mongodb named "warehouse_db". Now we need to see,

1. for any INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE in the "source_db" will reflect into the "warehouse_db" automatically
2. Create a view in "source_db" joining those three tables. We need to see, any changes in the view of "source_db" should reflect in a collection of "warehouse_db" and name that as "reporting_data"
3. Create a Power BI file and connect the " reporting_data". Present the data into Power BI in such a way, so that any changes in "source_db" will reflect into the Power BI file instantly.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have used Studio 3T for MongoDB but still its a manual method to replicate data into MongoDB 
I need solution for automatic data replication in real time.

Comment: You should add the table definitions to your Post, with some sample data.